# Customization of full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

i need to add buttons example:-Agenda button along with the existing three buttons for Month,Week,Day.
need help regarding this

Comment: Do you mean something entirely custom? Will the built in agenda view not work for your purposes?

Comment: It would be like the other three tabs...The agenda tab would display all the events following a certain priority..based on a certain priority algorithm

Answer (score 0):

To Add agenda View button

```
$('.fc-header-right').append('<span class="fc-button fc-button-agendaList ui-state-default ui-corner-right"><span class="fc-button-inner"><span class="fc-button-content">Agenda</span><span class="fc-button-effect"><span></span></span></span></span>');
    $('.fc-header-right .fc-button-agendaDay').removeClass('ui-corner-right').addClass('ui-no-right');
```

Performing click on agenda view

```
  $('.fc-button-agendaDay').click(function () {

alert('your custom logic goes here');   

});
```